# В каком значении используется слово «благословить» в русскоязычном переводе Библии?

Tags: значение-слов

> И **благословил** Бог седьмой день, и освятил его, ибо в оный почил от
> всех дел Своих, которые Бог творил и созидал.
>
> [[Бытие 2:3, текст из Викитеки](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5#2:3)]

Если взять, для примера, [Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), значения слова там следующие:

> **БЛАГОСЛОВИТЬ**...
>
> 1. *кого.* Перекрестить (рукой, крестом, иконой), произнося слова молитвы, напутствия, пожелания благополучия, успеха. *Б. детей перед сном. Б. молодых под венец. Благослови тебя Бог! Б. на дорогу* (отправляя в путь).
> 2. *кого, на что или с инф.* Выразить своё согласие, одобрение; напутствовать, желать благополучия. *Б. на ратный подвиг. Б. на добрые дела. Б. преданно служить науке. * Старик Державин нас заметил И, в гроб сходя, благословил* (Пушкин)
> 3. *кого-что.* Высок. Воздать хвалу, благодарность. *Б. судьбу. Б. Господа Бога за исцеление.*
> 4. *кого чем.* Шутл. Ударить. *Б. палкой по спине.* ...

Ни одно из этих значений не имеет смысла, подходящего под контекст *«благословил ... день»*. Что же имеется в виду?

В следующей цитате похоже на первое значение, но не совсем:

> Я **благословлю** ее и дам тебе от нее сына; **благословлю** ее, и произойдут
> от нее народы, и цари народов произойдут от нее.
>
> [[Бытие 17:16, текст из Викитеки](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5#17:16)]

Это больше похоже на наделение какой-то силой, а не просто на *«Перекрестить (рукой, крестом, иконой), произнося слова молитвы, напутствия, пожелания благополучия, успеха»*.

Интересно, что в первых двух цитатах в [английском тексте (в Викитеке)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Bible_(King_James)/Genesis) используется слово «bless» и [в англоязычной Википедии есть такое толкование:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blessing)

> In religion, a blessing (also used to refer to bestowing of such) is
> the infusion of something with holiness, spiritual redemption, or
> divine will.
>
> Если перевести без того, что в скобках:
> В религии благословение — это
> наделение чего-то святостью, духовным искуплением или божественной
> волей.

И это больше подходит по смыслу (наделение святостью или божественной волей), чем толкования в русских толковых словарях. Выглядит так, что для перевода использовано слово, которое не имеет в русских толковых словарях подходящего знания.

Если рассмотреть происхождения слова «благословить», то оно по сути означает «благо-словить», т. е. «хорошо говорить» о ком-то:

> **Благослови́ть.** Старославянская калька от греческого eulogein.
> Благословить буквально значит «хорошо о ком-нибудь говорить».
>
> [Этимологический словарь Крылова Г. А.]

Похожая история и с английским словом «bless». Отрывок из [словарной статьи на etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=bless):

> This word was chosen in Old English bibles to translate Latin
> benedicere and Greek eulogein, both of which have a ground sense of
> "to speak well of, to praise," but were used in Scripture to translate
> Hebrew brk "to bend (the knee), worship, praise, invoke blessings."
>
> Если перевести:
>  Это слово было выбрано в древнеанглийских библиях
> для перевода латинского benedicere и греческого eulogein, оба
> из которых имеют основное значение «хорошо говорить, хвалить»,
> но использовались в Писании для перевода еврейского brk «преклонять
> (колено), поклоняться, восхвалять, вызывать благословения».

С одной стороны, перевод словом «благословение» вроде правильный, потому что отражает суть «хорошо говорить», но с другой — в Ветхом Завете, из которого цитаты, нет греческого слова eulogein, потому что текст написан не на греческом, а на еврейском языке и использование кальки греческого слова выглядит не совсем понятным.

В одном месте (может их больше) действительно похоже на такой смысл:

> Я благословлю **благословляющих** тебя, и **злословящих** тебя
> прокляну; и благословятся в тебе все племена земные.
>
> [[Бытие 12:3, текст из Викитеки](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5#2:3)]

Второе употребление слова похоже не значение «хорошо говорить»:
*Я благословлю **хорошо говорящих о тебе**, и **плохо говорящих о тебе** прокляну; и благословятся в тебе все племена земные*.

Но первое и третье употребление слова ни как не похожи на «хорошо говорить». Такое значение также не подходит в *«**благословил** ... день»* или «***благословлю** ее, и произойдут от нее народы»*.

Какое же всё-таки значение у русского слова «благословить» подходящее по контексту, почему переводчики использовали это слово и почему в русских толковых словарях, как кажется, нет подходящего значения?

Есть ли где-то в каком-то словаре правильное толкование этого слова и как другими словами можно заменить его в тексте, чтоб было понятно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведённый вами перевод Библии -- это Синодальный, то есть дореволюционный (лишь приведённый к современной орфографии). Более того, даже на тот момент он был наполнен возвышенно-устаревшими словами. Ясно, что сверка по современным словарям не всегда что-то внятное даёт.
Поэтому для начала заглянем в «Словарь церковно-славянского и русского языка, составленный вторым отделением императорской Академии наук» (1847):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
,
а потом в два других авторитетных источника:

> Когда день благословляется, — говорит м. Филарет, — тогда он
> поставляется причастным особого некоего блага, достойным радости и
> сохранения среди самых перемен времени (цит. по: Лопухин А. П. Толковая Библия).

> В применении к Богу «благословлять» значит одарять благом (Библейский словарь).

(Замечу, что и на иврите использован глагол baw-rak', переводимый на русский именно как "благословил".)

Comment: В целом хороший ответ, я проголосовал и принял.

Comment: Первый словарь, который вы привели даёт определения применительно к Библии, это удобно.

Comment: Насчёт того, что _«…даже на тот момент он был наполнен возвышенно-устаревшими словами. Ясно, что сверка по современным словарям не всегда что-то внятное даёт»_: насколько я понимаю, более современные переводы, если именно говорить об этом слове, не отличаются. Хотя, конечно, у меня нет времени и сил сличать все переводы.

Comment: Поэтому вызывает некоторое непонимание, почему для перевода продолжают использовать слово, чтоб понять которое нужно лезть в специализированный словарь. Ведь если слово в языке в этом значении не используется, то его нельзя считать удачным переводом, мало кто его поймёт.

Comment: Насчёт глагола «baw-rak'». Я иврит не знаю и судить не могу. Дело в том, что переводить могут так по традиции, а ещё потому, что нет в русском языке другого более подходящего слова. Это надо почитать толкования на иврите, чтоб понять. Например, в английском языке бывает так, что какое-то слово переводится на русский язык определённым образом, но если мы почитаем толковые словари на русском и на английском, то оказывается, что это не совсем то же самое. Бывает так, что трудно средствами одного языка предать, что было сказано на другом языке.